# Optimizing a trigometric function

Tags: trigonometry, optimization

I have $f(\theta_1,\theta_2)=ep_1\sin^2(\theta_1)-ep_2\sin^2(\theta_2)$ in which $p_1 = const, p2=const$, $p_1+p_2=1$, $\theta \in (0..2\pi)$, $1 \ge e(\theta_1,\theta_2) \ge 0$

I am trying to find $e$ that maximize $f$. While $e$ is not necessarily a wave function, I think it makes sense if $e$ is in-phased with $sin^2(\theta_1)$ and out-phased with $sin^2(\theta_2)$. However I don't have the tool for such optimization in my math repertoire.

In case we want to be clear what maximize means, I mean that on average. So if $e'$ manage maximize $f$ on particular $\theta'_1, \theta'_2$, I am interest in the whole volume under the curve.